# Github pages won't render my images but everything works when on local host

Tags: html, github

[Here is my repository](https://github.com/Mfried95/Ping-validation)

I read some people has problems with the file being in capital(i.e PNG) or .. and //, however mine does not have any of these. I even changed my image to jpg from png.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is trying to access the images from the wrong place, if you look in the devtools you can see that the website is trying to find images here:

https://mfried95.github.io/images/illustration-dashboard.jpg

instead of here:

https://mfried95.github.io/Ping-validation/images/illustration-dashboard.jpg

You can change your image tags to no include the leading slash, so like this
`<img src="images/illustration-dashboard.jpg" alt="">` instead of `<img src="/images/illustration-dashboard.jpg" alt="">`

I'd do a google search on how to configure relative paths with github pages, but for now this should do it.